# Problema guardar Caracteres en MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, oracle

Estoy trabajando con PHP, Oracle y Mysql. Actualmente hago en mi sistema una consulta a una base de datos ORACLE y la traspaso a otra base de datos MYSQL. Mi problema es que al traspasar la información a MYSQL, los datos que tengan acentos o ñ, MYSQL los cambia por signos de interrogación ?.

**CONSULTA**

```
 include "../conexionOracle.php";

 $query = oci_parse($conn_oracle, "SELECT RUT, DV_RUT, NOM1, NOM2, 
 AP_PATERNO, AP_MATERNO
 FROM PERSONAS");

 include "../conexion.php";

 while ($row = oci_fetch_array($query, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) 
 {
   $query_2 = mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE alum
   SET 
   nombres = '$row[NOM1] $row[NOM2]', 
   apellidos = '$row[AP_PATERNO] $row[AP_MATERNO]'
   WHERE rut = '$row[RUT]'
 }
```

Los campos nombres y apellidos son Varchar y su cotejamiento es "utf8_general_ci".

**conexion.php**

```
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$password = '';
$db = 'miBD';

$conn = @mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$db);
mysqli_query($conn,"SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
```

**conexionOracle.php**

```
$userOracle = 'usuario';
$passwordOracle = 'pass';
$dbOracle = 'xx';

$conn_oracle = oci_connect($userOracle,$passwordOracle,$dbOracle);
```

Agradecería que alguien me pueda orientar o indicar que me esta faltando.

Comment: Prueba así: **`mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8");`**. OJO, pon el nombre correcto de la conexión, pues en una parte de la pregunta aparece `$conn` y en otra `$conection`, así que aclárate. Si sigue sin funcionar, depura el contenido que tienes con un `var_dump($row);` y revisa si es correcto. Si lo es, entonces muéstranos el `CREATE TABLE` de la tabla en cuestión.

Comment: Depuré el contenido con var_dump y la variable, y el valor ya viene con signos de interrogación antes de pasar a MYSQL. Lo raro es que en ORACLE esta correcto

Comment: Y cómo está configurado el encoding para PHP?

Comment: Y ¿cómo obtienes los datos desde Oracle en ese contexto de PHP? Supongo que conectarás a Oracle o algo. Revisa esa parte.

Comment: Edite la pregunta y agregue el código con la consulta a Oracle y después a MYSQL.

Comment: Queremos ver lo que hay en `conexionOracle.php`, sin que publiques tus credenciales de conexión, claro está. Puede que ahí no hayas seteado la codificación.

Comment: Edite la pregunta y agregue ambas conexiones.

Comment: Exacto. Pasa el charset como cuarto parámetro: **`$conn_oracle = oci_connect($userOracle,$passwordOracle,$dbOracle,'AL32UTF8');`** [Revisa los ejemplos del Manual de PHP para más detalles](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-connect.php). O bien simplemente: `$conn_oracle = oci_connect($userOracle,$passwordOracle,$dbOracle,'UTF8');` No sé cómo tienes los declarados los datos en Oracle...

Comment: Funcionó, te lo agradezco, gracias por su tiempo e interés para resolver este problema. Agréguelo como solución.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando haya problemas de codificación ten en cuenta lo siguiente:

1. Verificar que el HTML tiene una codificación adecuada
2. Verificar que PHP tiene una codificación adecuada
3. Verificar que la(s) conexion(es) tienen una codificación adecuada
4. Verificar que los datos están guardados correctamente en el origen (esto incluye una eventual fuente de datos, por ejemplo, cuando se toman datos de un archivo para guardarlos en la base de datos, y en ese archivo los datos no están bien codificados).

En el caso que expones, habiendo revisado los puntos 1, 2 y 4, entonces es claro que el problema está en las conexiones a la base de datos en el contexto de PHP. Para resolverlo, considera hacer lo siguiente:

#### Al conectar a Oracle

```
$conn_oracle = oci_connect($userOracle,$passwordOracle,$dbOracle,'AL32UTF8');
```

O bien:

```
$conn_oracle = oci_connect($userOracle,$passwordOracle,$dbOracle,'UTF8');
```

#### Al conectar a MySQL

```
# No silencies los errores con @, es una mala práctica
$conn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$db);
mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8");
```

Para más detalles sobre el problema de la codificación revisa la pregunta: *[¿Por que el Carácter inspector (�) aparece en algunos datos obtenidos de la Base de Datos?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/59489/29967)*.